# ImageMapster - jquery/html issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a few issues with the jquery plugin (ImageMapster). ImageMapster has provided a demo jsfiddle to test out their demo, they use one resource and the rest is right in front of you: http://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/396/

If you hover over the image, you will be able to several small boxes and when you hover over them, you will see a description under the image. (if it doesnt work then try clicking on the image itself). It uses the `area` tag.

I tried to use the same method and implement it on a normal HTML site. However, its not working and i cannot understand what i have done wrong to the jsfiddle that is not working.

Example SIte: http://www.nina-naustdal.com/index1.html

Its Exactly the same site, which is annoying. Can someone shed some light onto this issue.

Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your code in

```
$(function(){
   // Your code
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //Your code
});
```

You are accessing `#beatles` before loading it in DOM.

Its running under jsfiddle because it is wrapping in `$(window).load(function(){`